# Simulate a HTTP 408?

Tags: linux, http-status-codes, http-status-code-408

Is it possible for a server to simulate a http 408 error? A payment processor is trying to send a http post to my website and they say that in their logs a connection is being made but my server is responding with a http 408 after 0.1 seconds. Is it possible for them to send a 408 back instantly hence no actual timeout?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly a server can return a HTTP 408 error immediately, if it chooses to do so. This would be an abuse of the error code, but it is possible. You may want to use a packet sniffer to see if a 408 is being sent from your server, or from some upstream proxy.

Comment: Packet sniffing is beyond the scope of this question - head over to serverfault.com (the server administration sister site of stackoverflow) and open a separate question, please